# Last.fm geo.getEvents returns Invalid Method - No method with that name in this package

Tags: api, methods, geo, last.fm

I have a problem running a test query with geo.getEvents method to the last.fm API. Weird thing is that it has been working for a while, then it just stopped suddenly. I wonder if the method has been disabled, or am I doing something wrong?

This is the test query generated by api documentation on last.fm :
http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.getevents&location=madrid&api_key=44b222651afcfdc3244da1b97708be17&format=json

It always returns:

```
{"error":3,"message":"Invalid Method - No method with that name in this package"}
```

Other methods seem to work just fine.

Any pointers?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to make the request?

Comment: For anyone checking up on this issue:
I reported this problem 2 months ago: https://getsatisfaction.com/lastfm/topics/event-getinfo-and-geo-getevents-returning-error-no-method-name Unfortunately, no progress yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This and a lots of other errors  started with the relaunch of lastfm 3(!) weeks ago... and they are still not resolved.

Follow the dilemma here: https://getsatisfaction.com/lastfm/topics/api-known-issues

Comment: (unfortunately) this is the right answer at the moment. Apparently, there are few methods that stopped working completely. Forum thread is definitely useful, thank you.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with event.getInfo. Has not worked in weeks.

Comment: Same issue for artist.getEvent
Not working for months now!!

Comment: Unfortunatelly it's 2016 and it is still not working. Would really appreciate the events method of the LastFM API.